# Sanity Studio: conditionally hide fields based on value from a reference field

Tags: next.js, sanity

Is there a way to conditionally hide fields based on the value of a referenced field?

I have two types: `Destination` and `DestinationType`

Below is the reference from the `Destination` type to the `DestinationType` type:

```
defineField({
      name: "destinationType",
      title: "Destination Type",
      type: "reference",
      to: { type: "destinationType" },
    }),
```

There are only four `destinationType` docs: City, State, Country, Region. With the corresponding values set in the `destinationType.name` field.

Then in my `Destination` type have 4 other reference field:  `cityRef` , `stateRef`, `countryRef`, `regionRef`

I want to conditionally hide these fields based on the value of the `destinationType.name`

Below I tried to hide the cityRef if the destinationType.name does not equal City

```
defineField({
      name: "cityRef",
      title: "Destination City Reference",
      type: "reference",
      to: { type: "destination" },
      hidden: ({ parent }) => parent?.destinationType?.name !== "City",
      options: {
        filter: ({ document }) => ({
          filter: 'destinationType->name == "City"',
        }),
      },
    }),
```

I can’t seem to get this to work. I’ve tried 20 different ways.

The outcome I’m seeking is to show/hide the 4 {destinationType}Ref fields based on the current destination’s reference to `destinationType.name`

EG: if i set the `destinationType` to “Region” I want to hide cityRef, stateRef, and countryRed…and so forth.

Update: looks like I only have access to limited data on the reference as shown from the console.log output:

```
{
"_createdAt": "2023-02-19T17:26:48Z",
"_id": "8adb4138-d55d-48fb-9a2e-b6f78f1873a0",
"_rev": "VoO7lZqxqfzVYxXcTSOD38",
"_type": "destination",
"_updatedAt": "2023-02-19T17:26:48Z",
"destinationType": {
    "_ref": "8d818167-5ef4-4c99-bfe2-76463fb576fb",
    "_type": "reference"
},
"name": "New York City"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Conditional fields Examples](https://www.sanity.io/docs/conditional-fields#cb141da3da34) in Sanity.io docs.

> Hide based on a value in the current document
>
> Only show the subtitle field if the title field is truthy:

```
{
  name: 'subtitle',
  type: 'string',
  title: 'Subtitle',
  hidden: ({document}) => !document?.title
}
```

So in your case, *either* of these should work:

```
hidden: ({ parent }) => parent?.name !== "cityRef",
hidden: ({ parent }) => parent?.title !== "Destination City Reference",
```

The issue seems to be your use of `destinationType` which is unnecessary.

Comment: I unfortunately need the destinationType content type. This should work, but doesn't. Is it impossible to conditionally render the fields based on a reference?

Comment: If you try `hidden: ({parent}) => {console.log(parent); return true;}` as a test, what does `parent` show you?

Comment: {_createdAt: '2023-02-19T17:26:48Z', _id: '8adb4138-d55d-48fb-9a2e-b6f78f1873a0', _rev: 'VoO7lZqxqfzVYxXcTSOD38', _type: 'destination', _updatedAt: '2023-02-19T17:26:48Z', …}
destinationType
: 
{_ref: '8d818167-5ef4-4c99-bfe2-76463fb576fb', _type: 'reference'}
name
: 
"New York City"
_createdAt
: 
"2023-02-19T17:26:48Z"
_id
: 
"8adb4138-d55d-48fb-9a2e-b6f78f1873a0"
_rev
: 
"VoO7lZqxqfzVYxXcTSOD38"
_type
: 
"destination"
_updatedAt
: 
"2023-02-19T17:26:48Z"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

Comment: This object seems broken, `, ...} destinationType` - Can you place the entire object in code blocks in your post instead?